# How to split a string using regex

Tags: android, regex

I'm parsing a json file with this code:

```
JSONObject stationJson = array.optJSONObject(i);
Station s = new Station();
s.setName(stationJson.optString("name"));
s.setTimestamp(stationJson.optString("last_update"));
s.setNumber(stationJson.optInt("number"));
```

This is the json file :

```
{
"number": 123,
"contract_name" : "7500 - London",
"name": "nom station",
"address": "adresse indicative",
}
```

I would like to display just the "London" in the name section not the Number.

I found this Code Snippet but I don't know how to use it :

```
case spots:
            number = pSpotsJSON.optString("id");
            name = pSpotsJSON.optString("name");
            address = pSpotsJSON.optString("description");
            status = pSpotsJSON.optString("status");
            displayName = buildDisplayName(name);
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot parse spots from JSON: unknown provider " + provider.getName());
    }
}
private String buildDisplayName(String name) {
    String regexp = "[\\d\\s]*([a-zA-Z](.*)$)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
    if (m.find()) {
        return m.group();
    }
    return name;
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: you are looking to extract `"London"` from `"7500 - London"`. It is absolutely not related to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

What about getting a substring after the "-" of your String?

Would give something like this:

```
String contractName = stationJson.getString("contract_name");
contractName = contractName.substring(contractName.indexOf("-")+2); //+2 for the minus + space caracters
```